# Lock file for reading

Tags: go

I try to `Lock()` file for reading from another process, so I tried to do it in next way:

```
var (
    mutex = sync.Mutex{}
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start")
    go runZiper()

    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    f2, _ := os.Open("test_tmp.txt")
    // here will be writing to file
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second) //just for try
    f2.Close()

}

func runZiper() { // this process will compress file (files) in some period
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) //just for try
    f, err := os.Create("test_tmp.txt.zip")
    if err != nil { ... }
    defer f.Close()
    w := zip.NewWriter(f)
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test_tmp.txt")
    if err != nil { ... }
    fz, _ := w.Create("zipped.txt")
    fz.Write(data)
    w.Close()
}
```

but my `compressor` (function `runZip`) still can read and compress the opened file. So that I can lose information.

How can I avoid this situation?

I've tried to use `sync.Mutex` and `sync.RWMutex` but results were the same.

Comment: What is `compressor`?  I don't see that in your code. Your question is incomplete. We can't tell you how to fix what we can't see.

Comment: Are you under the impression that mutexes somehow affect other processes? That's not the case. Mutexes are used to synchronize goroutines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there has a smart way to solve this problem. when you close this file you can change the name of this file. On the other hand, we use the compressor to read another name like test_tmp1.txt.

```
func main() {
    go runZiper()
    f2, _ := os.Open("test_tmp.txt")
    // here will be writing to file
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second) //just for try
    f2.Close()
    err := os.Rename("test_tmp.txt", "test_tmp1.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func runZiper() { // this process will compress file (files) in some period
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) //just for try
    f, err := os.Create("test_tmp.txt.zip")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("test_tmp.txt.zip")
   }
   defer f.Close()
   w := zip.NewWriter(f)
   data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test_tmp1.txt")
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println("failed")
   }
   fz, _ := w.Create("zipped.txt")
   fz.Write(data)
   w.Close()
}
```